# jquery button name change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I've looked at other answers and tried a few things but I can't seem to get the name of the button changed. I know jquery is loaded fine and I'm able to execute simple alert scripts by clicking on the button. But the name change doesn't seem to work.
I've tried: attr and text functions. I've also tried "this" instead of '#toggleAutoPlayBtn'
Any other suggestions?

```
<input type ="button" id="toggleAutoPlayBtn" value="PAUSE"/>    



var autoStart = true;
    $(document).on('click', '#toggleAutoPlayBtn', function(){
                if(autoStart) {
                    $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').text('play');
                    autoStart = false;
               alert("play");
                } else {
                    $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').text('pause');
                    autoStart = true;
               alert("pause");
                }
    });
```

I am using:

Comment: have you closed the script in `<script>` tag

Comment: Yes I have with </script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `input type = button` for this you cannot use `.text()` method, since it is given in `value` attribute.  So retrieve it using

```
 $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').val('play');
```

else use `button` tag.

```
<button id="toggleAutoPlayBtn">PAUSE</button>
```

This will work now

```
 $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').text('play');
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed to val. And tried the second option too and it still doesn't work. No errors in the console either. A bit at a loss.

Comment: @user2502562 No it will work, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/4MD52/

Comment: Yah, I know, I've seen the fiddle for the val option too and it just doesn't seem to work. And it doesn't give any errors in the console either. Looks like the error is due to another issue. Here's the site I'm trying this on the website below. I put the button in the footer for now (I still have to figure out how to insert the button over the gallery area). And I still need to figure how to make the gallery actually stop (there will be an error for royalSlider there, it's not there if I take that one line of code) http://www.grantarchitecturestudio.com/projects/residence-3/residence-3-living/

Answer (score 2):

Buttons don't accept `.text()`

try this instead:

```
$('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').attr('value','pause');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use value attribute. Try the below methods based on what you are using.

For versions older than 1.6,

```
$("#toggleAutoPlayBtn").attr('value', 'play');
```

For versions newer than 1.6,

```
$("#toggleAutoPlayBtn").prop('value', 'play');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').val('play');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to use `val()`.

```
var autoStart = true
$(document).on('click', '#toggleAutoPlayBtn', function(){
    if(autoStart) {
        autoStart = false;
        $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').val('play');
        alert("play");
    } else {
       autoStart = true;
       $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').val('pause');
       alert("pause");
    }
});
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47t6F/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').val('play');` or `$("#toggleAutoPlayBtn").prop('value', 'play');`

This code will change value only once and not toggle every time you click the button unless you change value of `autoStart`.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#toggleAutoPlayBtn', function(){
        if(autoStart) {
            $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').text('play');
       alert("play");
        } else {
            $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').text('pause');
       alert("pause");
        }
 });
```

For toggle:

```
    var started = true;
    $(document).on('click', '#toggleAutoPlayBtn', function(){
                if(started) {
                    $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').val('play');
                    started = false;
                    alert("play");
                } else {
                    $('#toggleAutoPlayBtn').val('pause');
                    started = true;
                    alert("pause");
                }
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RH5G/)

Comment: Thanks. I changed to val. I did have autoStart = !autoStart; and I tried the exact code that you use that I see works in fiddle and it still doesn't work. No errors in the console either. A bit at a loss.

Comment: @user2502562 did you check console to check for errors?

Comment: I did, the only error it reports (before I even press the button) is: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.   Not sure if it's related to this.

Comment: Are you sure that function is being called with the click event?

Comment: I don't think it is, that's the only error that I think is somewhere else on the website. So I'm not getting any error messages related to this button. I can send you a link to the site where I have this button if that would help.

Comment: @user2502562 send. that will help

Comment: I put the button in the footer for now (I still have to figure out how to insert the button over the gallery area). And I still need to figure how to make the gallery actually stop (there will be an error for royalSlider there, it's not there if I take that one line of code)
http://www.grantarchitecturestudio.com/projects/residence-3/residence-3-living/

Comment: I see you are using wordpress. so change  $(document).on('click', '#toggleAutoPlayBtn', function() ----- to ----

jQuery(document).on('click', '#toggleAutoPlayBtn', function($)